# Could Angels and Demons die?

Tags: angels, death, demons

We know that Angels were created before Man. Trinity is uncreated and eternal i.e: sempiternal.

Could Angels and Demons be killed or die or lose their life according to Orthodox Christianity i.e: Catholic, Orthodox, Protestant?

I mean by death complete loss of both consciousness and memory. I mean by a life being both conscious and has a memory. This memory may be even one minute.

Comment: "We know that Angels were created before Man" We don't know that actually. As to your question, what do you mean by "life" and "death" in regards to angels and demons?

Comment: What like annihilated? Only a few denominations believe in absolute death. JWs teach that Satan and his demons will one day be annihilated.

Comment: In Catholic teaching, death is the separation of the soul from the body. Since angels and demons are spiritual beings with no bodies, they cannot die; indeed the notion of "death" makes no sense for purely spiritual entities.

Comment: @AndreasBlass for me Death is loss of both consciousness and memory. What is the meaning of spiritual being with no body?

Comment: @salah "Spiritual being with no body" means pure spirit. I added the redundant phrase "with no body" to emphasize why it makes no sense to talk about pure spirits (like angels or demons or God) dying.

Comment: @AndreasBlass please take this intriguing discussion with salah to chat.  Or, perhaps you can provide an answer that challenges the frame of the question. (I think you have most of the material for an answer outlined in your comments ...)

Comment: @AndreasBlass every being has beginning should have an end. The meaning of spirit is unclear. The meaning of spiritual being is unclear. For me God is body and something exceeding the body in the same time. The higher is both: the lower and himself in the same time.

Comment: @salah As I wrote in my first comment here, I'm writing about Catholic teaching. Since the opinions  expressed in your comments are inconsistent with Catholic teaching, you should probably just wait for someone else to answer on the basis of your religion and/or philosophy.

Comment: "I mean by death complete loss of both consciousness and memory" These are components of the body, but the body is only one component of the human creature. Souls of deceased persons appear conscious in the Bible all the time, just not in association with their bodies.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must know [what death means](https://asceticexperience.com/2020/01/what-is-death-in-the-bible/).

According with the above definition (courtesy of St. Gregory Palamas), you will see that there are two deaths.

Perhaps we must stress here, before answering, that both Angels and Demons in your text are ...Angels, because Devil is not a definition of species but a [definition of behavior](https://asceticexperience.com/2019/04/the-one-who-leaves-unity-for-money-is-like-judas/).

[Because angels (good and bad) are incorporeal](https://asceticexperience.com/2015/02/seraphim/) they are not subject of the first death.

So, since devils are good by nature but evil in intention, they are the only ones from the angels which suffer the second death.

Bonus point #1: Any intelligent entity (angel, human soul) is eternal by God's grace. It will not cease to exist.

Bonus point #2: Humans are the only ones which are subjects to the first death (all of us) and, possibly, subjects of the second death (God forbid!).